# A method for a near/far sighted person to see clearly?

Tags: optics, vision

In all the diagrams showing a near/far sighted eye, the image is formed either in front or behind the retina. But what if the person tries not to focus at the object he is looking at? What I mean is that if the person tries to focus his eye as if he was looking at an object farther than the object really is, the image will be formed on the retina(in case of near sightedness)and the reverse can be done for far sightedness, will this method work?

Comment: « the image is formed either to the right or to the left of the lens » You mean at a variable distance AFTER the lens?

Comment: Oh! it's a mistake, I meant retina.

Comment: the muscle of the iris will fidget to retain that and slip into blurry focus again and again

Comment: That's not true either way. In the case of vision disorders like the ones you mention, the image is formed at a distance from the surface of the retina, either in front or behind it. This is not about left or right.

Comment: Ya, I meant left or right according to the diagrams (ie. as seen from the side).

Comment: There is not much you can do without corrective lenses. A pinhole can improve focus by increasing the depth of field, which is why those of us who need reading glasses find them less necessary under bright lights.

Comment: The person with myopia or hyperopia IS consciously trying to change the focus of their eyes when viewing objects.  However, the refractive error in their eyes is beyond the ability of the lens in their eye to produce the correct focal length to view the object clearly.  That is why they have to wear corrective lenses.

Answer (score 0):

Well that's why short sighted people can still see at all. Their vision tries to accommodate with more or less difficulty because of extra muscular and attentional effort. But there is a limit to what the will can do to compensate for an imperfect optical system.